# Passing Abstract Class in Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing, abstract-class

Trying to call a static method from an abstract class inside an instanced class. This is a primitive coding example of what I'm trying to do, but not sure how to go about it.

```
DataSource myDataSource = new DataSource();
DataAdapterTest.initialize(myDataSource);

public abstract class DataAdapterTest extends DataAdapter {
    public static void initialize(DataSource d) {
        d.addDataAdapter(DataAdapterTest.class);
    }

    public static void onCreate() {
        does something here
    }
}

public class DataSource {
    public void addDataAdapter(Class<DataAdapter> c) {
        c.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: There is no problem using an Abstract Class in a method signature; the only real issue is one can't *instantiate* (i.e. `new`) an Abstract Class. The "real question" appears to be about [co]variance between `Class<DataAdapterTest>` and `Class<DataAdapter>`, which is effectively the same reason why `List<String>` is not assignable with `List<Object>` - in any case, include the relevant [compiler] errors.

Comment: `Class` objects can't be used this way (except with reflection which would probably be a very messy way to handle whatever it is you are doing). So you need to tell us more about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unclear. I'll answer to what I guess the problem is.

### Signature compile error

I guess you have the following compile error:

> The method addDataAdapter(Class) in the type
>   Main.DataSource is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Class)

Just use a wider signature for `addDataAdapter()`

```
public void addDataAdapter(Class<? extends DataAdapter> c) {
```

### onCreate call

You seem to be trying to use polymorphism with static methods, which is not a good idea since static methods are relative to a class.

```
c.onCreate();
```

You can't directly call a method from the class this way, because `c` is a `Class` object instance, and does not have such a method.
It is not the same as calling:

```
DataAdapterTest.onCreate();
```

You should pass an instance of the class instead of a `Class` object, and use instance methods instead of static methods. On this aspect, it is hard to give advice because we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

### Design problem

#### Needless `Class` parameter

You commented:

> I need the DataSource to be able to call a method of varying
>   DataAdapter abstract classes

The code you gave here only uses one class extending `DataAdapter`. If you need several, then put at least 2 in your minimal example.
As of right now, I don't see the need of passing on a class here. You could as well do the following:

```
DataSource myDataSource = new DataSource();
DataAdapterTest.initialize(myDataSource);

public abstract class DataAdapterTest extends DataAdapter {
    public static void initialize(DataSource d) {
        d.addDataAdapter();
    }

    public static void onCreate() {
        //does something here
    }
}

public class DataSource {
    public void addDataAdapter() {
        DataAdapterTest.onCreate();
    }
}
```

#### Needless static stuff

If everything in your `DataAdapterTest` class is static, then what is the purpose of extending `DataAdapter`? You can't use any inherited stuff without an instance of your child class.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to implement what I'm trying to do. I added two lines to the code above to help elucidate the process. Simply just want to pass a non-instanced reference of an abstract class to a method to call a static method of that abstract class passed.

Comment: @nuebKitsune The problem is that using a static method implies that you know the class. The class can't be dynamic in this process. Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: I need the DataSource to be able to call a method of varying DataAdapter abstract classes that are extended by the DataAdapter class; I didn't want instances of the DataAdapter class though simply because I didn't want to have to manage one or more instances of the class between activity classes in an Android project. The reason I need the DataSource class to access the DataAdapter class is because there is a method that gets called in the DataSource that requires the DataAdapter abstract classes take action to complete.

Comment: @nuebKitsune but why doing this in such a generic way? Do you actually have several different classes extending `DataAdapter`? If not, you  can use `DataAdapterTest.onCreate();` of course. If yes, then how would you use your static code anyway?

Comment: @nuebKitsune I edited my answer to explain my views about your design.

Comment: Downvoter, please care to comment so that I can improve my answer if something is wrong.